# Configure octomap with pointcloud from openni2

Tags: ros, octomap, openni2, xtion, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , i'm using rviz to visualize pointcloud from xtion through openni2. Could i have some help with configuration of octomap launch file to build map and visualize it in rviz . Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213293/configure-octomap-with-pointcloud-from-openni2/) by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All you have to do is to launch the octomap server, properly remapping the pointcloud topic, and set your global frame to whatever you are using, odom_combined should be OK. An example is given here:
https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/master/octomap_server/launch/octomap_mapping.launch

Your remap pointocloud topic would be most probably:  `<remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>`

Additionally, you have to launch rviz: `rosrun rviz rivz`, add a new display of type MarkerArray and subscribe to the topic `occupied_cells_vis_array`.

Obviously, you have to launch also the openni2 camera: `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch` (note you have to install openni2_camera and openni2_launch packages for this).

To put all that together in one launch file is straighforward and thus I let that to you :)

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-10**:
Ok, I made a launch file and seems to work, but now i can't see the map in rviz . How should i configure it ??

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-10**:
Run `rostopic echo /occupied_cells_vis_array` to ensure that the map is being published. The instructions to visualize it on Rviz are in the third paragraph of my answer.

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-10**:
I tried the command but nothing seems to be published. I show you the image of node graph to better understading the problem. [link text](https://imgur.com/x10ifYK).

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-10**:
Can you please share the launch file you created? I guess there is a problem with the frames, but cannot figure out which one.

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-10**:
[link text](http://wikisend.com/download/148226/test.launch) Here is it !

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-10**:
It's possible that is missing somewhere a tf ??

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-10**:
That is what I want to test. I was never sure how that works hehe.

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-10**:
Some news ???

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-10**:
Sorry I haven't had time for this, and I will busy during the weekend.